# GetStream.io: Error sharing the private key

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

I am developing an app with GetStream.io! I integrated the .js-File in my index.html and adjusted the right connection-requirements:

```
var client = stream.connect('...', '...', '...');
```

In the Browser-Console I get the following error:

> Error: You are publicly sharing your private key. Dont use the private key while in the browser.

Where should I put my secrets?

Thx for the Reply :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

you should store your API secret only on your servers (or on other trusted parties ). You can use feeds in the browser using server-side generated tokens.

eg.

```
// server-side (node.js)
var client = client.connect(api_key, api_secret);
var feed = client.feed('user', user_id);
var feed_token = feed.token;

// client-side (browser)
var client = client.connect(api_key, null);
var feed = client.feed('user', user_id, token);
```